# NIFI:how to handle paging in web service

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I  want  to get  service  data   which  have  paging  logic   like  this:  every  time  I  send   request,  it  can  get  only  700 mb  data  and  if   the response  data  for  certain  id is  more  than 700 mb I  will  have  to  invoke service  twice,  but  if  for  certain id  data is  more than 2800mb I  will have to invoke   service   four  times  and  if  one  of  the  part  of  this 2800 mb  will fail I mean  if  connection  error or  some  kind  of  error   will  happen

1. How  can I  recognize  which  part  of  same  id data  is  missing?
2. Can  you   advice  me  any  kind   of  architectual  solution which 
   can  simplify  this   process  inside  nifi   environment?

Comment: I guess an external script would do and store the id if bigger than ?, with that id run a get and apply a splitcontent/segementcontent with you limit.

Comment: ok  but  how  can i   controll  that  i  have  got  whole  data , i mean  if  any  kind  of  internal error  occured in service  during   this  process and  i have  error  code  insted of data   how  can i find   out  which  part  of  this  splitted service response data is missing?